# MVC COre dependency injection with service fabric get services after startup and before controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

Im in a situation where i have some some code that runs after startup but before a controller because Servicefabric normally initializes reliable collections after the comms has been loaded and configured ( eg Startup is completed) .

The question is how do i get access to the dependency injected services after startup and before a controller ( eg no httpcontext)  without parking it in some dirty hard to test static  ?

The other option is some very dirty constructor initialization . Does anyone else have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally have a global container now which i setup before Startup and i add in the builder via webBuilder.ConfigureServices(servicesAction) . Startup stays light.

I then use .AddSingleton with the factory method to late initialize SF collections.  ( I have also used AddTransient with a Func which keeps initializes the collection until success and then keeps returns it ).